# Django: How to split a form entry and save split elements into the same model,

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django so this may be pretty obvious. I want to have a form which is just one text area where some one can paste a list of names with each name on a new line. Then I want them to submit the form and the list to be separated and each name to have it's own entry into the database. I have a model set up called name. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('field_name')
        if text:
            for line in text.split('\n'):
                SomeModel.objects.create(field_name=line)
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me this way

```
def your_view(request):

    form = YourModelForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.POST.get("field")
        for i in text.split("\n"):
            modified=request.POST.copy()
            modified["field"]=i
            form=YourModelForm(modified)
            form.save()
```